# How to obtain a power curve from a likelihood ratio test for linear regression as a function of varying a coefficient of the more complex model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

I am currently doing a test of model complexities for two linear regression models:

First Model:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$

vs.

Second Model:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \epsilon$

and am using the `lrtest` function in `R` to do it. I would like to draw a power curve where the x-axis varies the values of $\beta_2$. The y-axis would report the power of the test at each value of $\beta_2$. Power is defined as the probability of rejecting the null when the null is false with the null being that the two models are the same.

I am wondering how I might be able to do such a test and if it can be done using the `lrtest` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can follow my idea presented here [Power Analysis for a mixed two-way ANOVA with unqual sample sizes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370734/power-analysis-for-a-mixed-two-way-anova-with-unqual-sample-sizes/371431#371431).

You need to generate the data according to the first model.

Need to specify the following: 1) sample size, 2)$\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, 3)$Var(\epsilon)$, 4)structure of $X_1$ and $X_2$, especially their correlation, and 5)$\alpha$ level.

Of course, you need the several different values of $β_2$ for x-axis.